# Getting constant error "publish timed out" on PubNub

Tags: android, pubnub

I've lunched the [PubNub sample Android app](https://github.com/pubnub/java/tree/master/android/3.4/examples/PubnubExample) and it works fine. Yet with my own pub/sub/secret keys, it doesn't.
While with Javascript in Chrome it works fine using my own keys. On Android i'm getting error "publish timed out" constantly.
Is it a known issue? How do I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Publish Timed Out Error on PubNub Network

This is an unhelpful error which is returned from the *error* callback within the PubNub **Android SDK** via Publish.  The error reporting service is being upgraded currently and will provide better feedback for debugging.  Currently the known errors which will occur on publish are the following:

#### Common Error Reasons

1. Invalid JSON
2. Message Too Large
3. Invalid **Publish Key** or **Subscribe Key**
4. Incorrect **Origin**

> Note that because the error reporting service will always return **"publish timed out"**, the actual error may be any of the above.

Valid JSON may be in the form of a **"String"**, **123** (number), **[1,2,3]** (array) or an **{ 'object' : 'data }** (object).

Messages can be up to **32K** in size!  We charge based on your average usage not your peaks.  Also, make sure to double check your API Keys are in the correct order

> PubNub is on Mashape!  Visit our API Playground - https://www.mashape.com/pubnub/pubnub-network/ - and learn about some of the REST Endpoints available on the PubNub Global Real-time Network.

Comment: And in the meantime, if you contact support@pubnub, we can nail down the exact cause for you.